# Rails and RSpec: For raise_error: what type of error is raised when a string is saved into a decimal datatype column?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm trying to write an RSpec 3.3.1 test for an invalid input. In this case, I'm trying to make this test work:

```
RSpec.describe Stat do  
  before do
    @stat = FactoryGirl.build(:stat)
  end  
  describe "creation" do
    subject { @stat }
    context "should be invalid" do
      it "when weight is a string" do
        @stat.weight = 'a'
        expect(@stat).to_not be_valid
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This is the validation I have in my Stat model:

```
validates :weight,   presence: true, format: { with: /\A\d{1,3}\.\d\z|\A\d{1,3}\z/ }
```

The data type for weight is Decimal.

I think I should use "raise_error" instead of "be_valid" but I don't know what error message it matches to and what block I should be in there.

How can I get this test to pass?

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this with Postgres 9.3 and Rails 4.2, and was as suprised as you to learn that Rails will accept strings without raising any error, as:

```
model.decimal_column = "foobar"
model.save
=> true
```

Subsequently, `model.decimal_column.to_s` yields `0.0`.

This may seem nonsensical at first, but it's actually just a surprising behavior from the way that Ruby's `BigDecimal` class works. The setter of an `ActiveModel` `decimal` column implicitly calls `to_d` on the input. `String.to_d` (http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/bigdecimal/rdoc/String.html#method-i-to_d) in turn calls `BigDecimal.new`, which has a special rule for strings: any unrecognized (i.e. non-numeric) characters terminate the value.

What does this mean? In a repl, try:
    "123foobarbaz".to_d
    => 123.0
    "foobarbaz123".to_d
    => 0.0

So when you set `model.weight = "a"`, the `weight` attribute is actually set to `0.0`. You can observe this if you stick a binding in there and inspect the model's values right before the `expect()` call.

In this case, you'll need to validate at the application layer to get your test passing. Depending on the needs of your application, there are a few options:

1) If `0.0` doesn't pose any particular problems for your application, you might simply add a front-end validation (JS or HTML) and let users know that it's not going to work.

2) If it's implausible that Stat ever has a weight of `0.0`, you could validate that the value is greater than 0.

3) It's a little heavy-handed, but you could redefine the setter for the model and raise your own error. For example:

```
def weight=(value)
  raise ArgumentError if value.is_a?(String)
  write_attribute(:weight, value)
end
```

This `raise` isn't really for a *validation*, but rather for the actual act of calling the setter method, which is why I've used `ArgumentError` here. That's definitely open to debate, though.

Hopefully one of these options ends up being helpful to you!

Comment: Ironically, if that were true for me, I think my test would work. I'm using rails 4.0.8 and it throws an error message.

Comment: Nevermind, I see what you're saying now. I'm getting the same thing. Is this a rails bug?

Comment: More of a surprising behavior than a bug. Reading the ruby docs for `BigDecimal`, it seems that strings in the input to a BigDecimal terminate the numeric input, but *don't make it invalid*. I'll expand on this in my answer above, and see if I can't come up with a better solution for you.